# CellList widget number cannot be over than 25

Tags: gwt

I have working on CellList for weeks now and I find it owesome.

Those days I wish to print a list that contains more than 70 elements but I noticed that my CellList doesn't append more than 25: from 0 to 24. To make sure that the problem has no relashionsip with my project, I decided to test the code in a new and clan project but It has the same result.

Here is my code:

```
CustomCell bodyCell = new CustomCell();
CellList<String> coreCellList = new CellList<String>(bodyCell);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<74; i++) {
    list.add("hello_"+i);
}
coreCellList.setRowData(0, list);
coreCellList.setRowCount(list.size(), true);

RootPanel.get().add(coreCellList);
```

and CustomCell:

```
public class CustomCell extends AbstractCell<String> {
interface Templates extends SafeHtmlTemplates {

        String style = "cell";

        @SafeHtmlTemplates.Template("<div class=\"" + style
                + "\" style = 'height : 15%'>{0}<br/></div>")
        SafeHtml cell(SafeHtml value);
    }

    private static Templates templates = GWT.create(Templates.class);

    @Override
    public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
            String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        SafeHtml safeValue = SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(value);

        SafeHtml rendered = templates.cell(safeValue);

        sb.append(rendered);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: With some more reserches, I've found a method that called `setPageSize(int i)`. By default, the page size is 25. So to show all the widgets, you should use `setPageSize(int i)` and give it the number of my widgets.

I hope this will save time for someone else!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use the code below passing my CellTables and CellLists when I don't want pagination.

```
public static void setupOnePageList(final AbstractHasData<?> cellTable) {
    cellTable.addRowCountChangeHandler(new RowCountChangeEvent.Handler() {
        @Override
        public void onRowCountChange(RowCountChangeEvent event) {
            cellTable.setVisibleRange(new Range(0, event.getNewRowCount()));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your experience

Answer (score 0):

CellList is using paging by default, having a page size of 25. If you add a SimplePager to your page, you can control which data you want to display.

I would advise not to disable paging by setting the page size to the size of your list of data, as you will run into serious performance issues with older browsers (especially IE8 and earlier), depending on the complexity of your presentation and size of the list.

For adding the Pager, see [the DevGuide](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#paging):

```
// Create a SimplePager.
SimplePager pager = new SimplePager();

// Set the cellList as the display.
pager.setDisplay(cellList);
```